# How to suppress py.test internal deprecation warnings

Tags: python, pytest

Is there a way to suppress the pytest's internal deprecation warnings?

Context: I'm looking to evaluate the difficulty of porting a test suite from `nose` to `pytest`. The suite is fairly large and heavily uses `nose`-style `yield` based test generators.

I'd like to first make sure the *existing* tests pass with pytest, and then maybe change test generators to `parameterized`.

Just running `$ pytest path-to-test-folder` with pytest 3.0.4 is completely dominated by pages and pages of

```
WC1 ~repos/numpy/numpy/lib/tests/test_twodim_base.py yield tests are deprecated, and scheduled to be removed in pytest 4.0
```

Is there a way of turning these warnings off?

Answer (score 178, accepted):

From `pytest --help`:

```
--disable-pytest-warnings
                      disable warnings summary, overrides -r w flag
```

Comment: As the help text says, this will only omit the textual summary. The result will still be yellow and show that there are warnings.

Comment: Better to put in the pytest.ini file, as shown below.

Answer (score 223):

I think you do not want to hide all warnings, but just the ones that are not relevant. And in this case, deprectation warnings from imported python modules.

Having a read on pytest documentation about [Warnings Capture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/capture-warnings.html):

> Both -W command-line option and filterwarnings ini option are based on Python’s own [-W option](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html?highlight=#cmdoption-W) and [warnings.simplefilter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.simplefilter), so please refer to those sections in the Python documentation for other examples and advanced usage.

So you can filter warnings with python's `-W` option!

It seems that `pytest` completely removes filters, because it shows all those `DeprecationWarning` when running, and Python's documentation about [Default Warning Filters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#default-warning-filter) clearly says:

> In regular release builds, the default warning filter has the
> following entries (in order of precedence):
>
> ```
> default::DeprecationWarning:__main__
> ignore::DeprecationWarning
> ignore::PendingDeprecationWarning
> ignore::ImportWarning
> ignore::ResourceWarning
> ```

So in your case, if you want let say to filter types of warning you want to ignore, such as those `DeprecationWarning`, just run the pytest command with `-W` option :

```
$ pytest path-to-test-folder -W ignore::DeprecationWarning
```

**EDIT**: From [colini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/825105/colini)'s comment, it is possible to filter by module.  Example to ignore deprecation warnings from all sqlalchemy :

```
ignore::DeprecationWarning:sqlalchemy.*:
```

You can then list your installed modules that creates too much noise in the output of `pytest`

**EDIT2**: For more precise control, the Python documentation about [Describing Warning Filters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#describing-warning-filters) states that the general way to write such warning filters is:

> `action:message:category:module:line`

**Use with file rather than in command line:**

You may prefer list those filters in pytest.ini file :

```
[pytest]
filterwarnings =
    ignore::DeprecationWarning
```

Comment: To filter on the module you use a regex.  Example to ignore deprecation warnings from all sqlalchemy modules:`ignore::DeprecationWarning:sqlalchemy.*:`

Comment: @colini that failed for me as an argument to the -W flag, but it worked for me in my pytest.ini file.

Comment: In pytest 6.1 the trailing regex isn't working for me, but you can insert a regex in the middle to match against the beginning of the warning message. `ignore:.*U.*mode is deprecated:DeprecationWarning` ignores all warnings of type DeprecationWarning where the start of the message matches the regular expression ".*U.*mode is deprecated". [more info](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/warnings.html#deprecationwarning-and-pendingdeprecationwarning)

Comment: @WhiteHotLoveTiger same with `ignore::DeprecationWarning:tensorflow[.*]` - only works for the configuration files, filed a bug report: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/8751

Comment: @MattSanders I also noticed that I cannot get module regex matching to work. Did you check if it is only a pytest issue? In my case it turned out to be even more fundamental: Even with a plain `PYTHONWARNINGS="..." python -c "..."`, module matching doesn't seem to work as the documentation describes it. Post as a [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71112211/1804173).

Answer (score 138):

`pytest -p no:warnings`, or add the following to your pytest.ini or tox.ini:

```
[pytest]
addopts = -p no:warnings
```

The result will be green without any indication of warnings. See documentation at https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html#disabling-warnings-summary.

This can be a valid use case for a test suite where you want clean output.

Be aware that always hiding all warnings may cause you to miss important warnings. [If you want to hide only specific warnings, look at Cloc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53218641/451480).

Comment: `addopts = -p no:warnings` is REALLY BAD idea, and CloC solution is much saner,  but I had to use yours when `ignore::InsecureRequestWarning` was not recognized, so you get +1 too

Comment: Disabling **all** warnings persistently (i.e. using pytest.ini) is almost never a good idea. Disabling just Deprecation warning (and by module) as CloC describes is the right way to do this.

Answer (score 26):

In the pytest.ini file you can add:

```
[pytest]
addopts = -p no:warnings
```

**OR** passing below line in the command-line. This might be useful if your test suites handle warnings using an external system.

> -p no:warnings

**OR** if you only want to hide some specific deprecated warning, add below statement in you pytest.ini file

```
[pytest]
filterwarnings =
    ignore:.*U.*mode is deprecated:DeprecationWarning
```

This will ignore all warnings of type DeprecationWarning where the start of the message matches the regular expression ".*U.*mode is deprecated".

**OR Although not recommended, you can use the**

> --disable-warnings

command-line option to suppress the warning summary entirely from the test run output.

Answer (score 17):

I don't want to hide all warning, so I put this in `pytest.ini`

```
[pytest]
filterwarnings =
    ignore::DeprecationWarning
```

Answer (score 11):

Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69622325/30038) for how to suppress warnings if you are using `pyproject.toml` file as configuration.

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
testpaths = ["./tests/unit"]
filterwarnings = ["ignore:::.*third_party_package.module:123", "ignore:::.*another_module*"]
```

`123` in this case is a line number to be suppressed

For more information on the general way to write warning filters, see the python official doc at "[The Warnings Filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#the-warnings-filter)" and "[Describing Warning Filters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#describing-warning-filters)".
In short, Individual warnings filters are specified as a sequence of fields separated by colons: `action:message:category:module:line`

Comment: `filterwarnings = ["ignore::DeprecationWarning"]` to ignore all deprecated warnings for this situation

Answer (score 3):

I want to add that it is also possible to filter the warnings in a fine-granular way by understanding the parsing mechanism which is well explained [in the warnings section of the python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#describing-warning-filters).

> Individual warnings filters are specified as a sequence of fields separated by colons:
> `action:message:category:module:line`

This allows you to e.g. disable a specific warning with a specific message for a specific module only. For me, it was using [pytest-freezegun](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-freezegun/), but not showing the annoying `DeprecationWarning` for using *distutils Version classes*.

Without applying the described filter from below the relevant output part from pytest runner is:

```
.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytest_freezegun.py:17: 34 warnings
tests/test_folder1/test_1.py: 10 warnings
tests/test_folder1/test_2.py: 4 warnings
  /my/project/path/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytest_freezegun.py:17: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
    if LooseVersion(pytest.__version__) < LooseVersion('3.6.0'):

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/capture-warnings.html
```

And with this setting in `pyproject.toml`, the `DeprecationWarning` for not using `packaging.version` is completely gone, but only for pytest-freezegun (because I do not want to deactivate all deprecation warnings for the whole project):

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
testpaths = ["./tests"]
filterwarnings = ["ignore:.*distutils Version classes.*packaging.version:DeprecationWarning:pytest_freezegun"]
```

In detail:

```
ignore:.*distutils Version classes.*packaging.version:DeprecationWarning:pytest_freezegun
^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
action       message (regular expression)                  category           module
```

Note: I do not want to include the line number, because library code could be changed without fixing the `DeprecationWarning`.

*(The possibility of filtering has also been mentioned in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40710094/how-to-suppress-py-test-internal-deprecation-warnings/60326186#comment95546938_53218641), but I wanted to elaborate a little more.)*

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to ignore all the warnings from the pytest file itself.
Just add the following in your pytest file:

```
import warnings; warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use a `setup.cfg` file, put this in:

```
[tool:pytest]
addopts = -p no:warnings
```

You need `tool:pytest` instead of just `pytest`, but it will tell you:

> Failed: [pytest] section in setup.cfg files is no longer supported, change to [tool:pytest] instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
${PYTHON} -m pytest -W ignore::DeprecationWarning
```

DeprecationWarning Will help remove the imports decrecations warning coming up when we run pytest .

This can be used in makefile.py to ignore the warnings

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

when working with multiple warnings,

```bash
python -m pytest -W ignore::DeprecationWarning -W ignore::ImportWarning
```