# How to ignore all warnings except from one package in pytest?

Tags: python, warnings, pytest

When running pytest, I would like to ignore warnings from third-party packages. I know how to ignore one specific package (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53218641/2057762), but how do I ignore all but one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set two filter rules:

```
[pytest]
filterwarnings =
    ignore
    default:::mypackage.*
```

You can apply multiple filters, so ignore everything and re-allow warnings for your package. The last one has highest precedence. Filter syntax is `action:message:category:module:line`. Possible actions and more details can be found in [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warning-filter).