# pytest - Suppress DeprecationWarning from specific 3rd party modules

Tags: python, pytest

When I run pytest I'm getting some deprecation warnings from a 3rd party library. I'd like to be informed about any deprecation warnings in my own code, but not in a vendored copy of a library bundled with another 3rd-party library.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53218641/1224068) was helpful in getting me partway there. If I run pytest like this:
`$ pytest ./tests/` I get:

```
$ pytest ./tests/
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.4, pytest-5.2.1, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.13.0
rootdir: /home/whlt/repos/tj-image-resizer/tests, inifile: pytest.ini
collected 5 items                                                              

tests/test_file1.py .                                                   [ 20%]
tests/test_file2.py ....                                                [100%]

=============================== warnings summary ===============================
/home/whlt/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/_collections.py:1
/home/whlt/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/_collections.py:1
  /home/whlt/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/_collections.py:1: DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated, and in 3.8 it will stop working
    from collections import Mapping, MutableMapping

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html
======================== 5 passed, 2 warnings in 2.54s =========================
```

but if I run pytest like this: `$ pytest ./tests/ -W ignore::DeprecationWarning` I get:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.4, pytest-5.2.1, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.13.0
rootdir: /home/whlt/repos/tj-image-resizer/tests, inifile: pytest.ini
collected 5 items                                                              

tests/test_file1.py .                                                   [ 20%]
tests/test_file2.py ....                                                [100%]

============================== 5 passed in 2.61s ===============================
```

This second output shows me that the filter works, but that will also hide any deprecation warnings I'd like to seeing resulting from my own code.

Part of this issue is that I'm not sure which module to try referencing in the ignore filter. I've tried `$ pytest ./tests/ -W ignore::DeprecationWarning:urllib3.*:` and I've tried `$ pytest ./tests/ -W ignore::DeprecationWarning:botocore.*:`. Both of these result in the same output as the first example with no filtering.

How can I filter out DeprecationWarnings from the version of `urllib3` packaged with the vendored version of `requests` included with `botocore` (which gets called when I run commands with the `boto3` library)?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You should use the warning filters options (ini or marks):

```
[pytest]
filterwarnings =
    ignore::DeprecationWarning:botocore.*:
```

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#default-warning-filter

"Individual warnings filters are specified as a sequence of fields separated by colons:"

```
action:message:category:module:line
```

Comment: Thanks, this will allow me to filter out all deprecation warnings where the message matches a given regex. I'm really interested in filtering them out based on module though.

Comment: @WhiteHotLoveTiger Edited. Also, saw you commented on the referenced question. Did it work?

Comment: Yeah, I've finally got it working via the ini file with `filterwarnings = ignore::DeprecationWarning:botocore.*:`. This is the same filter I had tried on the command line, so I'm still confused about why it works in the ini file but not with the `-W` flag.

Comment: Have you tried `pytest ./tests/ -W ignore::DeprecationWarning:botocore.*` ?

Comment: Tried just now. It gives the same result, showing the unwanted warnings :(

Comment: Where do I put the contents of that first code snippet? I put it in `pytest.ini`, next to my `*.py` files, invoked with `python3 -m pytest *.py`, and the warning is still there.

Comment: The answer I needed for an hour. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

if you are using `pyproject.toml` file for pytest configuration you can use:

```
 [tool.pytest.ini_options]
 testpaths = ["./tests/unit"]
 filterwarnings = ["ignore:::.*third_party_package.module:123", "ignore:::.*another_module*"]
```

`ignore:::.*third_party_package.module:123` ignores in specific warning at specific line
`ignore:::.*another_module*` ignores all warnings in the module.

Notice that you can have multiple ignores. You need to list them in []. Also, you can't have `*third_party_package/module:123` you must replace all `/` with `.`

Comment: Note that the syntax here is from the upstream warnings filter: https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#the-warnings-filter

Answer (score 4):

The answer from @Santiago Magariños does not work for me (but it put me on the correct path to find solution - so many thanks).

I use Python 3.9, pytest 6.2.1 and trying to suppress warnings from selenium 3.141.0.

I have realized that I need to prepend `.*` before the module name:

```
[pytest]
filterwarnings = ignore:::.*.selenium
```

or use the full "path". So to suppress the warning

```
../../../../../../.local/share/virtualenvs/common-bjARi2zp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py:28
  /home/vaclav/.local/share/virtualenvs/common-bjARi2zp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py:28: DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence \ 
    """Constructor, takes a WebDriver instance and timeout in seconds.
```

I need to use this filter in `pytest.ini` file:

```
[pytest]
filterwarnings = ignore:::.home.vaclav..local.share.virtualenvs.common-bjARi2zp.lib.python3.9.site-packages.selenium
```

Comment: Is it possible to use cut the path before the module itself? Let's sat I have the modules, for which I want to ignore warning, in a folder (not a package) named ```mods```. Can I use ```.*.mods``` or does it have to be package.

Comment: I gues it is possible. But I think it should be easy for you to test it and let us know the result ;-) @User10482

Comment: Tried it and didn't work. Was curious if there's some workaround.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly what the title says, but you might prefer to filter out warnings from **all** third party modules. To do that I use this in my `pyproject.toml` (or similar in `pytest.ini`)

```ini
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
filterwarnings = [
    "ignore::DeprecationWarning::",  # ignore deprecations from all modules
    "default::DeprecationWarning:mymodule.*:",  # except from mymodule
]
```