# Suppressing DeprecationWarning invalid escape sequence from specific modules in pytest6

Tags: python, pytest

We recently updated to pytest-6.2 and have discovered a dependency that is quite noisy with `DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence` warnings, which I know needs fixing, but is out of my control.

This noise is a distraction from the module under test, and I would like to suppress these warnings

I have added the following to my pytest.ini

```
filterwarnings =
    ignore::DeprecationWarning:module_name.*
```

And suppressions work for things like:

```
 DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated since Python 3.3, and in 3.10 it will stop working
```

But I still get `invalid escape sequence` warnings:

```
DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence \s
```

Is there are reason for this?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50821160/11246056

Comment: Thats where I got the syntax and example for mine above, so it helped, but it doesn't answer the specific question about `DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence`

Comment: `ignore:*.invalid escape sequence.*:DeprecationWarning:`?

Comment: Yup, that works, but also includes my modules, I just want to hide noisy dependencies for which I have little/no control.