# Why does Python's filterwarning module regex not work as expected?

Tags: python, warnings

According to the [Python warnings documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html) the filterwarnings pattern is `action:message:category:module:line`, and the `module` part should allow for matching specific modules against a regex. I'm trying to make this work to filter specific warnings for third party library modules, but the feature doesn't seem to work.

**Minimal example**

A simpler way to reproduce the issue is to create a file

**`my_module.py`**

```
print("\d")
```

and then run `PYTHONWARNINGS="error,ignore:::.*" python -c "import my_module"` from the same directory. Clearly the regex `.*` should match the module name `my_module`, but somehow it doesn't. The question is why?

**Original example**

As an example: Importing `rosbag` package (some package that comes with the [Robot Operating System (ROS)](https://www.ros.org/) distribution) triggers an error when running in "strict" report-warnings-as-errors mode:

```sh
$ PYTHONWARNINGS='error' python -c "import rosbag"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/<PATH-TO-ROS-DISTRIBUTION>/lib/python3/dist-packages/rosbag/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from .bag import Bag, Compression, ROSBagException, ROSBagFormatException, ROSBagUnindexedException
  File "/<PATH-TO-ROS-DISTRIBUTION>/lib/python3/dist-packages/rosbag/bag.py", line 1568
    matches = re.match("#ROS(.*) V(\d).(\d)", version_line)
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid escape sequence \d
```

That makes sense, it should use a raw string literal.

Now I'm trying to use a module regex to silence the warning from the `rosbag` module. For the purpose of the example I'm specifying the filterwarnings via `PYTHONWARNINGS` but other methods like via pytests settings result in the same behavior.

I'm getting the following unexpected behavior:

- using `PYTHONWARNINGS='error,ignore:invalid escape sequence::'` works. Of course that filters all "invalid escape sequence" warnings. So let's add a `module` regex at the end to be module specific...
- using `PYTHONWARNINGS='error,ignore:invalid escape sequence::rosbag.*'` should do exactly that, but the filter doesn't seem to match. The warning is still reported as error as with plain `error`.
- even using `PYTHONWARNINGS='error,ignore:::.*'`, which should in theory match any module, fails to match. Only removing the regex entirely like `PYTHONWARNINGS='error,ignore:::'` matches, but of course that is essentially equivalent to just `PYTHONWARNINGS='ignore'`.

Any ideas why the module regex is not matching at all?! Is this a Python distribution bug? I'm on Python 3.8.10 / Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-W) states: "The module field matches the (fully-qualified) module name; this match is case-sensitive." (The syntax for `PYTHONWARNINGS` is the same as for `-W`). As far as I can see, this is not a regex, but the full string. I just made a couple of quick tests that confirm that. None of the components use regex-matching.

Comment: I tried the plain module name as well of course, but it is not matching either. The [actual warning documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/warnings.html) states: _module is a string containing a regular expression that the module name must match._ The docs even show an example `error:::mymodule[.*]`, which demonstrates that it is supposed to be a regex.

Comment: You are right, that is what is stated - I had overlooked this. With PYTHONWARNINGS I couldn't get any regex to work (while full module names worked, though I haven't tested with your specific module).

Answer (score 7):

As of Python 3.10, this is the intended behavior. Warning filters set through `-W` and `PYTHONWARNINGS` currently only match literal strings for the message and module.

This is a known discrepancy in the Python documentation, and is tracked in [this CPython issue](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/78805). There were some discussions and [a PR](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/9358) to add regex support, but these ultimately went nowhere. [This open PR](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/23172) adds further clarification to the docs.

Comment: Interesting. At least under Python 3.8 I cannot get it to work even when not using a regex and trying to match the module name literally. I.e., `PYTHONWARNINGS="error,ignore:::my_module" python -c "import my_module"` also errors (same with adding a `.py` suffix), which is still not what the adapted docs specify.

Answer (score 0):

For ones looking for a workaround to suppress warnings in third-party modules and keep shown for developed packages and/or modules. Say I have developing `mypackage`. I use a shell wrapper runner script that does following:

```
FLT="$(cd "./src"; find mypackage/ -name '*.py' | \
    sed -e 's/\.py//g' -e 's/\/__init__//g' -e 's/\//./g' | \
    { while read module; do
        echo "default:::$module"
    done; echo "default:::__main__"; } | paste -sd,)"

export PYTHONWARNINGS="ignore,$FLT"
```