# How to ignore specific warning using Pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

Pytest has [@pytest.mark.filterwarnings](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/warnings.html#pytest-mark-filterwarnings)

using:

```
@pytest.mark.filterwarnings("ignore::DeprecationWarning")
```

works like a charm but I don't want to ignore all DeprecationWarning
I want to ignore a specific one:

```
warnings.warn("Please use new_module.", DeprecationWarning)
```

I tried to do:

```
@pytest.mark.filterwarnings("ignore::DeprecationWarning: Please use new_module.")
```

but this doesn't work. I can't find the proper syntax to filter a specific message.

how can this be done?

Comment: This should answer your question -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/60326186/13261176

Comment: @TeejayBruno how so? it doesn't say anything about specific warning